# Gmaps v3 change close img in InfoWindow and others styles

Tags: google-maps-api-3

It's possible to change the default close img of infoWindows ?
More, can change de complete infoWindows design changing the main style ?
[infoWindow](http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/iw3.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these libraries http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries

Comment: No other way using direct api code to change in place to add libs

Answer (score 0):

I just did it like this:

```
// Add listener to window on DOM ready to replace close icon with something else.
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow,'domready',function(){
    var newImage = $('<img src="path/to/img"/>');
    $(".gm-style-iw").next("div").html( newImage );
});
```